# Script to move files

Tags: shell

I used a script to create sub-directories based on the file names of all my mp4 files. My files and newly created sub directories, of the same name, are located in the smae sub directory. Now I need a script to move the mp4 files into each of the files corresponding sub directories. I hope this makes sense. ex: I would like to move "crank (2006).mp4" to the sub directory named "crank (2006)". I have about 1200 of these files to move to their already created sub directories. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the .mp4 suffix uses `%%` to delete the sub-string `.mp4` from the end of the `$f` variable.

The `mkdir` statement ensures that the sub-directory does exist before the `mv` command.

```
for f in *.mp4
do
    subdir="${f%%.mp4}"
    mkdir -p "$subdir"
    mv "$f" "$subdir"
done
```

Comment: To be safe, I would still execute `mkdir -p "$subdir"` first, to make absolutely sure the directory exists and the file is moved, rather than renamed in the original directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
mmv 'smae/*.mp4' 'smae/#1/#1.mp4'
```

This is much safer than (noddy) scripts as `mmv` will check for loops, name collisions, possible problems in the move before moving any file etc.

Comment: `mmv` is not a standard program.

Comment: True. Should be IMHO. Available in most distros (and cygwin if that's your poison)

Answer (score 0):

Following code will,

- find the .mp4 files in current directory,
- create sub-directories based on the file names of all mp4 files,
- move each of the files to corresponding sub directories

  ```
  for f in *.mp4; do path=$(ls $f | rev | cut -c 5- | rev); mkdir $path; mv $f $path/. ; done
  ```

**Ex:** if "crank (2006).mp4" is available into current directory than new sub directory named "crank (2006)" will be created into current directory and "crank (2006).mp4" file will be moved into that sub-directory.

**NOTE:** instead of "mv" you can also use "cp" for copy files